# upload image only

Tags: post-thumbnails, frontpage, featured-post

I create post page from front end , and i add code for uplaod feature image.
I use this code

```
    if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        }
         if ($_FILES) {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) $error_array[]='STOP';
                $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
            }   
        }
        if ($attach_id > 0){
            //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
            update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
        }
```

It's work.
But i want upload only image

How can i do it ?

Comment: and what does this let you upload?

Comment: the code is upload multi files type [pdf / jpg / rar ... etc] i want upload only image

Comment: check the extension on the front end via JS...|
Or check the $_FILES array prior to sending it to media_handle_upload() do you have an example of a var_dump of the $files array?

Comment: yes i want example .. iam not developer

Comment: I'm asking do YOU have an example... 
Ok do this: var_dump($_FILES); and tell us the output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited code

```
    if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        }
         if ($_FILES) {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
            $mime = $_FILES[$file]['type'];
            $filesize = $_FILES[$file]['size'];
            $maxsizef = 524288;
            if($filesize > $maxsizef) $error_array[] = 'error size, max file size = 500 KB';
            if(($mime != 'image/jpeg') && ($mime != 'image/jpg') && ($mime != 'image/png')) $error_array[] ='error type , please upload: jpg, jpeg, png';
                $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
            }   
        }
        if ($attach_id > 0){
            //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
            update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
        }
```

it's work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer to your question is really well documented in the code you're using:

```
 //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
 update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
```

So all you have to do is to comment the following line: 
`update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);`